# how receive data from apple server notification in spring boot project

Tags: in-app-purchase

how to define the endpoint on spring boot server to receive server notification after read the app [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications), this is what I am doing now:

```
@Api
@RequestMapping("/post/notification")
@FeignClient(name = "dolphin-post-service")
@Validated
public interface IAppleServerNotificationController {

    /**
     * Receive Apple Server Notification
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/v1/appleSeverNotification")
    Response<Integer> handleNotification(@RequestBody @Valid ServerNotificationRequest request);
}
```

and this is the entity I am define:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServerNotificationRequest implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "responseBody")
    @NonNull
    private String responseBody;

}
```

but It seems not work. where I am going wrong? Any suggestion?

```
@Override
    @NoCheck
    public Response<Integer> handleNotification(ServerNotificationRequest request) {
       
        JSONObject jsonResult = JSONObject.parseObject(request.getResponseBody());
        AppleServerNotificationRecord record = new AppleServerNotificationRecord();
        record.setResponseBody(request.getResponseBody());
        record.setNotificationType(jsonResult.getString("notification_type"));
        int result = notificationRecordService.saveNotificationRecord(record);
        return new Response<>(result);
    }
```

the responseBody is null!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the request entity like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServerNotificationRequest implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_adam_id")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_adam_id")
    private String autoRenewAdamId;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_product_id")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_product_id")
    private String autoRenewProductId;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_status")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_status")
    private String autoRenewStatus;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_status_change_date")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_status_change_date")
    private String autoRenewStatusChangeDate;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_status_change_date_ms")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_status_change_date_ms")
    private String autoRenewStatusChangeDateMs;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_status_change_date_pst")
    @JsonProperty("auto_renew_status_change_date_pst")
    private String autoRenewStatusChangeDatePst;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "environment")
    private String environment;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "expiration_intent")
    @JsonProperty("expiration_intent")
    private Integer expirationIntent;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "notification_type")
    @JsonProperty("notification_type")
    private String notificationType;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "password")
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String sharedSecret;

    //@ApiModelProperty(value = "unified_receipt")
    //@JsonProperty("unified_receipt")
    //private String unifiedReceipt;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "bid")
    private String bid;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "bvrs")
    private String bvrs;

}
```